# I am learning DevOps basic steps and my task was create CICD Pipeline using jenkins and Docker on Maven Project From Repository

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

Error
It shows me error that docker daemon might not be running

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[CICD-Maven-Jenkins-Docker-Integration] $ docker build -t imdhruv28/cicd-docker-jenkins-integration --pull=true /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CICD-Maven-Jenkins-Docker-Integration
time="2020-03-24T14:27:15+05:30" level=error msg="failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied"
error during connect: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&pull=1&rm=1&session=3maudqn4r7n8md6azfdxz34vb&shmsize=0&t=imdhruv28%2Fcicd-docker-jenkins-integration&target=&ulimits=null&version=1: context canceled
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8

EXPOSE 8081

ADD target/CICD-Docker-Jenkins-Integration.jar  CICD-Docker-Jenkins-Integration.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/CICD-Docker-Jenkins-Integration.jar"]
```

```
can any one will help me to solve this?
```

Comment: Is Docker running on the machine where the Jenkins is?

Comment: how to check that?

Comment: Run any command, e.g. `docker version` and see if it responds.

Comment: Yes, it gives me response output for server and client seperetaly

Comment: Then it's probably the second thing [taleodor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2948891/taleodor) said. Check if the user that executes Jenkins job is in `docker` group.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible options here:

1. Docker daemon is indeed not running
2. The user executing your pipeline is not added to `docker` group

Algorithm to debug would be to first check manually if Docker is actually running, second verify which user is used by Jenkins to execute the pipeline (add `whoami` to the pipeline to print), finally make sure that that user is added to `docker` group.